# How is it possible to get approval from Google Play reviewers on the permissions restricted by the new personal loans policy of Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, android-permissions

Our (non-bank) app relates to the personal loans industry and as a service provider, it is our duty to control users' financial transactions while ensuring the security of financial transactions through risk management and anti-fraud policy based on KYC standards.

For improving our app's core functionality we need to collect users' data that comes from Android permissions: Read_external_storage; Read_contacts; Access_fine_location; Read_phone_numbers. But recent changes in the personal loans policy of Google Play prohibit the implementation of such permissions https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9876821.

All of my justifications to Google Play reviewers were rejected with reference to the new personal loans policy of Google Play. Despite this, I can see similar (non-bank) apps with all or part of that permissions included in their App info.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.